# fatal error: 'SFS2XAPIIOS/SmartFox2XClient.h' file not found

Tags: apportable, smartfoxserver

I build a game using cocos2d and smartfox2xclient library.
I try using "apportable load" to port this game to android platform but I get error like this:
fatal error: 
      'SFS2XAPIIOS/SmartFox2XClient.h' file not found

Did apportable support smartfox library? And how can I fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve the missing header file issue by making sure that the header paths are correct in the Release.final generated file. If the path is missing, you can add it to the head_paths section of add_params in configuration.json.

However, Apportable doesn't bundle a smartfox integration and if smartfox doesn't provide full Objective C source, you will need to take a different approach and [bridge](http://docs.apportable.com/using-java.html#using-java) to their Java API.